# Apache/ PHP set-up - adding the dll file tp httpd file means the server will not restart

Tags: php, apache, apache2

I'm trying to set up my PHP with Apache on a Windows 7 64 machine, with IIS set up as well.

Everything is ok with the installation (I get the 'It works!' page etc) but I cannot seem to get PHP to run on the localhost.

I've got it down to this. When I add the following lines to the httpd file, and try to restart Apache, Apache does not start. I get a "The requested operation has failed!" notice.

The lines breaking the system are:

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:/PHP"
```

Where LoadModule is put at the end of all the LoadModule lines and the PHPIniDir is put at the end of the httpd doc.

Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot dump any random PHP DDL you find into your Apache directory and get it working automatically. You need a PHP binary that matches your Apache binary: 32/64-bit, VC version, thread-safe... Also, error messages are saved into Apache logs.

Comment: what error of Apache says?

Comment: OK, the logged error is "Syntax error on line 130 of C:/Apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll into server: The specified procedure could not be found. " - it should be the correct dll file as far as I'm aware?

Comment: Logs suggest it isn't. Feel free to *edit* your question and add info about your Apache and PHP binaries.